# How to get relative mouse movement in python with pynput

Tags: python, mouseevent, mousemove, pynput

I wanted to know, how i can get relative mouse movement. I know i can calculate it with 2 absolute coordinates of the mouse, but I want to get the relative mouse movements directly, because the other method would not work for my problem. Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

Try using pynput library.

```
pip install pynput
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

# Read pointer position
print('The current pointer position is {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))

# Set pointer position
mouse.position = (10, 20)
print('Now we have moved it to {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))

# Move pointer relative to current position
mouse.move(5, -5)

# Press and release
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)

# Double click; this is different from pressing and releasing
# twice on macOS
mouse.click(Button.left, 2)

# Scroll two steps down
mouse.scroll(0, 2)
```

Source: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

Comment: I know the pynput libary, but is there also a listener there or in another libary that only outputs the relative mouse movements as a vector or something like this?